# Trying to update a table between two forms without success in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a project that has several classes with winform
I use a binding list to update the table. I have a main form that contains the table and another form that is used to update and receive data.
I am trying to update the table in the userform
The update works fine for me but is not reflected directly in the table only after exiting and returning to the current form
This is the part of the code that is relevant

```
existingMotorcycle.Yearofmanufacturer = int.Parse(yearofmanufacuremotorcycletextBox.Text);
                            existingMotorcycle.Enginevalume = int.Parse(enginevaluemotorcycletextBox.Text);
                            existingMotorcycle.Color = colormotorcyclecomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
                            existingMotorcycle.Price = double.Parse(pricemotorcycletextBox.Text);
                            existingMotorcycle.Instock = int.Parse(instockmotorcycletextBox.Text);
                            existingMotorcycle.Wheelsuitableforterrain = WheelsuitableforterraincheckBox.Checked;
                            existingMotorcycle.Arethereshockabsorbers = _ArethereshockabsorbersmotorcyclecheckBox.Checked;
                            existingMotorcycle.Model =modelmotorcycletextBox.Text;

                            MessageBox.Show("Motorcycle updated successfully", "Success" MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            rentalshopmain.RefreshTable<Motorcycle>();

 private BindingList<Motorcycle> motorcycles;
        private BindingList<Bus> busList;
        private BindingList<Truck> truckList;
        private Rentalshopmain rentalshopmain;

        public Usmotorcycle(BindingList<Motorcycle> motorcycles1)
        {
            InitializeC`f`omponent();
            this.motorcycles = motorcycles1;
            rentalshopmain = new Rentalshopmain(busList, truckList, motorcycles);`



  public partial class Rentalshopmain : Form
    {
        private Timer imageChangeTimer;
        private BindingList<Truck> truckList;
        private BindingList<Bus> busList;
        private BindingList<Motorcycle> motorcycleList;
        private BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        private WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
        private int count = 0; // Initialize count
      



      public Rentalshopmain(BindingList<Bus> SavedBus, BindingList<Truck> SavedTruck, BindingList<Motorcycle> SavedMotorcycle)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            truckList = SavedTruck;
            busList = SavedBus;
            motorcycleList = SavedMotorcycle;


      }


Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
              BindingList<Bus> bus = new BindingList<Bus>();
              BindingList<Truck> truck = new BindingList<Truck>();
             BindingList<Motorcycle> motorcycle = new BindingList<Motorcycle>();
           
            Application.Run(new Rentalshopmain(bus, truck, motorcycle));



 public void RefreshTable<T>()
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Bus))
            {
                BindingList<Bus> busRef = VehiclesManager.GetVehiclesByType<Bus>();
                bindingSource.DataSource = busRef;
                dataGridViewvihechle.DataSource = bindingSource;
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Motorcycle))
            {
                BindingList<Motorcycle> motorcycleRef = VehiclesManager.GetVehiclesByType<Motorcycle>();
                //bindingSource.DataSource = motorcycleRef;
                dataGridViewvihechle.Update();
                dataGridViewvihechle.DataSource = motorcycleRef;
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Truck))
            {
                BindingList<Truck> truckRef = VehiclesManager.GetVehiclesByType<Truck>();
                bindingSource.DataSource = truckRef;
                dataGridViewvihechle.DataSource = bindingSource;
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(vehicleRental))
            {
                BindingList<vehicleRental> vehicleRentalRef = VehiclesManager.GetVehiclesByType<vehicleRental>();
                bindingSource.DataSource = vehicleRentalRef;
                dataGridViewvihechle.DataSource = bindingSource;
            }

            if (dataGridViewvihechle.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridViewvihechle.CurrentCell = dataGridViewvihechle.Rows[0].Cells[0];
            }
        }

public class VehiclesManager
    {
        private static BindingList<vehicleRental> vehicleRentals;

        static VehiclesManager()
        {
          //  vehicleRentals = new BindingList<vehicleRental>();
            vehicleRentals = FileUtils.LoadVehiclesFromFile();
        }

        public static void RemoveVehicle(vehicleRental vehicleRental)
        {
            vehicleRentals.Remove(vehicleRental);
        }

        public static void AddVehicle(vehicleRental vehicleRental)
        {
            vehicleRentals.Add(vehicleRental);
        }

        public static BindingList<vehicleRental> GetVehicles()
        {
            return vehicleRentals;
        }

        public static BindingList<T> GetVehiclesByType<T>() where T : vehicleRental
        {
            BindingList<T> requestedVehicles = new BindingList<T>();
            foreach (var vehicle in vehicleRentals)
            {
                if (vehicle is T)
                {
                    requestedVehicles.Add(vehicle as T);
                }
            }
            return requestedVehicles;
        }

        public static void SaveVehicles()
        {
            FileUtils.SaveVehiclesToFile(vehicleRentals);
        }

        public static void SaveVehicle(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            FileUtils.SaveVehiclesToFile(vehicleRentals);
        }
```

I managed to update the variable in the list but cannot reflect the change in the table through the user form.